# docker compose file not working: services.wordpress Additional property port is not allowed

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am using the below codes but docker-compose file not working. I need to setup WordPress in docker for different environment.

ERROR: services.wordpress Additional property port is not allowed
[image]

Code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes: 
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD : password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    port:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite

networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's "ports" (plural) that can accept a list, delimited by "-" and not 'port' (singular). Kindly check the below docs for docker compose file (yaml)
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/